# CSS dropdown menu disappears when using bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have a dropdown nav menu (using css from w3schools) that works fine until a carousel is put immediately after. Then the dropdown no longer shows and I do not know why.
I am new to css html .., so I don't find the solution to my problem. I have changed the Z-index and position on multiple classes and it doesn't solve the issue. Whenever i delete the bootstrap css link then the dropdown menu works again.
Do you have any suggestions?
thanks!

ps: i put all the code, sorry if i added more than the required, its my first time posting

```css
/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.background-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url("../img/header.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #1C8CE8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.activenav {
  background-color: #4F47E1;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.carousel {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img {
  height: 600px!important;
  width: 100%;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="activenav">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Products 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Make</a>
        <a href="#">Model</a>
        <a href="#">Year</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contactus">Contact us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="Functionnav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </nav>
  <section id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/img1slideshow.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>title</h3>
          <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img2slideshow.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>title</h3>
          <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img3slideshow.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>title</h3>
          <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what is size of your images ?

Comment: they are quite big, 2560 × 1213 pixels, so I included this to avoid them being so big in the screen .carousel-inner>.item>img {
  height: 600px!important;
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: I tried with bootstrap tutorial its working fine. check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with css property **overflow** in the menu wrap. Use my below's code,
 hope it helps

```
.dropdown {overflow: initial;}
.topnav {
   overflow: visible;
   width: 100%;
   height: 53px;
}
```

Comment: Yes. this is where exactly is missing this. Upvoting this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately when i added it it did not work. it created another block under the initial one (with news about and contact us) and it just partially displayed the dropdown...

Comment: you have to add this at bottom of your css then it will wrk. i tried this its work.

Comment: great! it worked when i added z-index: 100 to .dropdown class. another question then: why should I add that at the end? thanks!
solution for me:
.dropdown {overflow: initial;z-index 100}
.topnav {
   overflow: visible;
   width: 100%;
   height: 53px;
}

Comment: I realized that while it solves the issue for a wide screen, when i narrow the screen the responsive @media does not work properly...

Comment: @rgc, First tell me why you have used this code in the media device **.topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
}**

Comment: to my understanding (again, I am very new at it and I have been following w3school, so most likely im mistaken) this is to make the nav bar options disappear so then a hamburger icon can appear holding the menu inside on click.

Comment: @rgc please share your  javascript file then I will understand better

Comment: thank you for your help, the javascrip i have is:
function Functionnav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") { 
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

Comment: @rgc your javascript is working fine. If you set the background in this element **.topnav.responsive a** then you will be able to see your links. Cause your link's color is **#f2f2f2**

Comment: I just modified the color but still the side nav bar, when in a small screen, doesnt show well (it just shows the dropdown menu). Do you have any other idea? thanks in advance!

Comment: @rgc Use this code at the responsive device. I hope this will work **.topnav.responsive {height: auto;}**

Comment: @rgc you are welcome and you are so good. If you need any help just knock me i will try to help you cause i like to help good people. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a solution adding z-index on the carousel or dropdown?

Comment: I tried using z-index on both, setting it to 0 or negative in carousel and higher on dropdown, but it did not solve the issue. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You done changes to code. If you use direct code it will works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  /* CSS Document */

 
</style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"> Make</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Model</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Year</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/2ade48/fff" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e02ae0/fff" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i tried your code as is and worked, however i was thinking on using another style for the dropdown (hover, no round edges, no space between navbar and carousel etc).I suppose i can modify those options, but I was trying to understand what did i do wrong. If i don't find another solution I will use this one, so thank you for your help!

Comment: which link you refer for this ? so that we can help